# The TinyMCE doesn't have access to a theme (Symfony2)

Tags: symfony, tinymce

I've tried to install the TinyMCE in the Symfony2. But I always see following error:

```
"Failed to load: http://noxaeterna/js/tinymce/themes/simple/theme.min.js"
```

I think that is happened because the Symfony2 handles that as a route. So is there the way to solve that problem?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Please show screenshot with project tree, and path to this theme on your disc.

Comment: The /var/www/noxaeterna/ directory is a main of project. «http://noxaeterna» is the prod entry point which is located at /var/www/noxaeterna/Symfony/web/. So link «http://noxaeterna/js/tinymce/themes/simple/theme.min.js» is /var/www/noxaeterna/Symfony/web/js/tinymce/themes/simple/theme.min.js.

Comment: Ohh I've checked. There is no such theme!